# PHP and MYSQLi - Bind parameters using loop and store in array?

Tags: php, content-management-system, mysqli

Below is my code for the function I am using to retrieve multiple data from my table, but I would like to use bind_result($array[0],...,..) to be generated automatically depending on number of fields i am selecting in the query.

for example..

```
$query=select a,b,c,d,e from table;//selecting 5 fields
......
$stmt->execute();$stmt->bind_result($retrieve[0],$retrieve[1],$retrieve[2],$retrieve[3],$retrieve[4]);
```

(the bind_result for 5 values should be automatically generated)
Help will be appreciated ...Thanks

```
$query="SELECT comment, userid,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtime)
                FROM comment_updates
                WHERE updateid=46546
                ORDER BY dtime DESC
                LIMIT 10 ";
        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($comments[0],$comments[1],$comments[2]);
            $i=0;
            while($stmt->fetch()){
            $i++;
            $name='t'.$i;
            $$name = array($comments[0],$comments[1],$comments[2]);
            }
            return array($i,$t1,$t2,$t3,$t4,$t5,$t6,$t7,$t8,$t9,$t10);
            $stmt->close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php

This will get you the number of fields in your resultset via `mysqli_num_fields()`.

This should be the size of your `$retrieve` array.

As `bind_result` doesn't take an array as an argument, you'll need to use `call_user_func_array` to achieve this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $retrieve_references);
```

`$retrieve_references` should be an array of references to the elements in `$retrieve`. Using `$retrieve` itself in `call_user_func_array` will trigger an error.